# javascript JSON parse initialize value

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse json to js object with data. this is my simple example :

```
var IsTrue = true;
var Number = 9;
var Object = { a : 1};
var Array = [10,6];

var jStr = '{"ask" : IsTrue, "value" : Number, "obj" : Object, "arr" : Array}';
var js = JSON.parse(jStr);
console.log(js);
```

I work in this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/n4tLgp5k/1/

I get error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I

i wish i can parse json to js object and variable in object initialized value with initialized variable before.

Comment: Don't use `eval()`, use `JSON.parse`, `JSON.stringify` on object [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4tLgp5k/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reference to variable inside the string so you can't parse it using `JSON.parse()`. Convert the string to valid JSON, you can do it using`JSON.stringify()`.

```js
var IsTrue = true;
var Number = 9;
var Object = {
  a: 1
};
var Array = [10, 6];

var jStr = '{"ask" : ' + JSON.stringify(IsTrue) + ', "value" :' + JSON.stringify(Number) + ', "obj" : ' + JSON.stringify(Object) + ', "arr" : ' + JSON.stringify(Array) + '}';
var js = JSON.parse(jStr);
console.log(js);
```

---

If you just need to create the object then you can use **[object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)** and if need json string you can use `JSON.stringify()`

```js
var IsTrue = true;
var Number = 9;
var Object = {
  a: 1
};
var Array = [10, 6];

var js = {
  ask: IsTrue,
  value: Number,
  obj: Object,
  arr: Array
};

console.log(js);
```

---

Also there is baddest way using `eval()` but I will not prefer this method .

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

```js
var IsTrue = true;
var Number = 9;
var Object = {
  a: 1
};
var Array = [10, 6];

var jStr = '{"ask" : IsTrue, "value" : Number, "obj" : Object, "arr" : Array}';
var js = eval('(' + jStr + ')');
console.log(js);
```

Comment: Don't encourage use of `eval()` when there are simple ways to convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pure string before parsing.

```
var IsTrue = true,
    Number = 9,
    Object = { a : 1},
    Array = [10,6];

var jStr = {"ask" : IsTrue, "value" : Number, "obj" : Object, "arr" : Array};
var js = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jStr));
console.log(js);
```

But I am not sure why you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason for using a string, why not use an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) like this?

```
var IsTrue = true;
var Number = 9;
var Object = { a : 1};
var Array = [10,6];

var js = {
    "ask" : IsTrue, 
    "value" : Number, 
    "obj" : Object, 
    "arr" : Array
};
console.log(js);
```

Although you should avoid using types as variable names. Number, Object, Array are all terrible variable names. If it doesn't cause a parse error it's certainly going to confuse someone sometime. And that someone might be your future self.

Comment: Remove quote from `}';`

Comment: This is just creating an object, OP is interested in creating a **JSON** object

Comment: Except he then tries to JSON.parse(str) which returns an object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Secondly, once he's created the object, he can then turn that back into a JSON string if that really was his original intention.

Comment: `var js = JSON.parse(jStr);` is the second last line of his code, before logging the resulting object to console.